# What is this tile set with the card suites and numbers set in a 6x6 grid?

Tags: identify-this-game

What is the name of this game?

How do you play it? (if instructions cannot be easily found online)

---

Board and Game Pieces:

[image: Board and Game Pieces]

Board and Back of Game Pieces:

[image: Board and Back of Game Pieces]

The game also includes:

- 12 White Poker Chips
- 8 Maroon Poker Chips
- 4 Blue Poker Chips

---

Notes:

- The pieces in the first image may not be in their proper places

Comment: I'm guessing it's some sort of bid tracking system, maybe for Bridge. Or, maybe it's not. It's one of the two.

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer, maybe for this question. Or, maybe it's not. It's one of the two.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: This look a lot like sequence (Dice version) or kazink board games , but is surely not them.
Could as pointed out be a bid tracking system.
Is there any markings on the black holding rack or another piece? Will edit this post later after more research

Comment: After double checking, there are no markings unique to any of the pieces (other than the suites and numbers / icons displayed in the images)